# Can we change the point form $\not p = m$ to $\not p = 0$ in on-shell renormalization scheme condition?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics

In the on-shell scheme, in QCD, one can impose the counterterms action to vanish the part of 1PI diagrams on external lines. The on-shell condition can be written as follows:
\begin{equation}
{\left. {\frac{{d\Sigma }}{{d\not p}}} \right|_{\not p = m}} = 0
\end{equation}
Can one consider another condition like 
\begin{equation}
{\left. {\frac{{d\Sigma }}{{d\not p}}} \right|_{\not p = 0}} = 0
\end{equation}
to cancel the 1PI diagrams on off-shell lines with $p^2 =0$ ? I saw this approach in a PHD thesis, but it seems wrong!